Proving $(a\times b)+(b\times c)+(c\times a)$ is perpendicular to plane $ABC$
Given $a,b,c$ -- vectors from the origin to points $A,B,C$, show that the vector $(a\times b)+(b\times c)+(c\times a)$ is perpendicular to the plane $ABC$
This problem is from Hassani Mathematical Methods.
I have tried expanding them using $a\times b=\det\begin{pmatrix}\hat{e}_1&\hat{e}_2&\hat{e}_3\\
a_1&a_2&a_3\\b_1&b_2&b_3\end{pmatrix}$.
But it doesn't really seem to work.

Note that all three vectors are individually perpendicular to the plane. So any linear combination of them will also be perpendicular.

@CyclotomicField How to show that they are individually perpendicular?

They are not.  For example,  let  the vectors be (1,0,0)   and (0,1,0) and (0,0,1).

The plane is spanned by $b-a, c-a$. Show the above is perpendicular to both. Note that you can compute $x^*(a \times b)$ using a suitable determinant.

How about
\begin{align}
(a-b)\times(b-c) &= a\times b - a\times c - b\times b + b\times c \\
&= a\times b + c\times a - 0 + b \times c \\
&= a\times b+b\times c+c\times a
\end{align}
Both $(a-b)$ and $(b-c)$ are in the plane so their cross product must be perpendicular to it.

Wow, that's a really good approach.

Lemma:  given a plane $P$ (not necessarily through the origin)   and a nonzero vector $v$  in $R^3.$  IF $p \cdot v$  is a constant $C$  for every  point $p$ in the lane,  THEN  $v$ is perpendicular to the plane.
Proof:  take any two (distinct) points in the plane, $p_1, p_2.$  Then $$(p_1 - p_2) \cdot v = p_1 \cdot v - p_2 \cdot v = C - C = 0.$$
Next, your plane is written as convex sum
$$   r a  + sb + t c  $$
meaning that
$$  r+s+t = 1 $$
Computation with your cross product term $(a\times b)+(b\times c)+(c\times a)$ shows that   the dot product is constant
$$  ( r a  + sb + t c) \left( (a\times b)+(b\times c)+(c\times a) \right)    $$
is just $r + s + t$   times the triple product $a \cdot (b\times c) .$
But $r+s+t=1$   and $a \cdot (b\times c) $   is a certain determinant, namely the (signed) volume of the parallelopiped generated by vectors $a,b,c.$
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Triple_product#Geometric_interpretation
So, there you go, constant dot product, orthogonal by the Lemma.

It is sufficient to prove that the given expression, ie.
$$\vec{a}\times \vec{b}+\vec{b}\times \vec{c}+\vec{c}\times \vec{a}$$
Is perpendicular to both $\vec{a},\vec{b}$.
Since $\vec{a},\vec{b}$ span the plane ,$\vec{c}=\alpha \vec{a} + \beta \vec{b}$
For some real numbers $\alpha$ and $\beta$.
$ \implies \vec{b}\times \vec{c}=-\alpha\vec{a}\times \vec{b}.$
Hence as said by @CyclotomicField, since they are all perpendicular to the plane, the given expression is too.
